# XDocument.Save creating 3 bad characters in XML

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, linq-to-xml

using (XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(fcService.SetCIRIFilePath(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                debts.Save(xw);
                xw.Flush();
            }

My debts object is a XDocument object which I populated using LINQ to XML. However when I save it, it looks fine in notepad, but when opened with a binary/hex editor it shows these 3 characters at the start of the XML:

```
ï»¿<?xml version
```

This is stopping it being parsed by a 3rd party. Any ideas how I can stop it doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try telling the UTF-8 encoder not to produce the Byte-order-mark, like this:

```
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2.aspx
using (XmlWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(fcService.SetCIRIFilePath(), new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            debts.Save(xw);
            xw.Flush();
        }
```